# Can SMS generate "alter table" code when tables are beeing changed?

Tags: sql, ssms

In PHPMyAdmin there is an option to get changes to a database in sql code (and php if I remember correctly).

Is this possible on Microsofts platform?

If I for example have this table:

```
create table test (
id int,
text varchar(5)
)
```

and when I add a column, can I get the "alter table code" for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

- Right-click on the table name in Management studio and select `Design`.
- Make your changes
- **Before** you save the changes, click the `Table Designer` menu and select `Generate Change Script..`

A window will appear which will have the SQL script.

If you don't want to save it to a file, you can select the text and copy it (Ctrl-A doesn't work unfortunately)